# How do I move items from lst1 that are present in lst2 to the end of lst1 in Python?

Tags: python, string, append

How do I check if certain items from lst2 are present in lst1, and for all items that are, move them to the end of lst1? For example, I have lst1: "pineapple", "apple", "orange", "banana", "pear", and lst2: "apple", "banana". I want lst1 to become: "pineapple", "orange", "pear", "apple", "banana".

Right now I'm doing it like this:

```
f = open('bestuursleden.txt', 'r')
bestuur = f.read()
bestuur = " " + bestuur
bestuur = bestuur.split(",")
f.close()

f = open('namenlijst.txt', 'r')
studenten = f.read()
studenten = " " + studenten
studenten1 = studenten.split(",")
f.close()

studenten2 = sorted(studenten1, key=lambda x: x.split()[-1])

if ('apple' in studenten2):
    studenten2.append(studenten2.pop(studenten2.index('apple')))
if ('banana' in studenten2):
    studenten2.append(studenten2.pop(studenten2.index('banana')))
if ('orange' in studenten2):
    studenten2.append(studenten2.pop(studenten2.index('orange')))
if ('pineapple' in studenten2):
    studenten2.append(studenten2.pop(studenten2.index('pineapple')))
if ('raspberry' in studenten2):
    studenten2.append(studenten2.pop(studenten2.index('raspberry')))
if ('strawberry' in studenten2):
    studenten2.append(studenten2.pop(studenten2.index('strawberry')))
if ('watermelon' in studenten2):
    studenten2.append(studenten2.pop(studenten2.index('watermelon')))

studenten3 = (','.join(studenten2))
studenten3 = studenten3[1:]
f = open('Gesorteerde lijst.txt', 'w')
f.write(studenten3)
f.close()
```

I think there should be some way to do it more efficiently, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use:

```
lst1 = ["pineapple", "apple", "orange", "banana", "pear"]
lst2 =  ["apple", "banana"] # you may cast to set for performance

intersection = []
difference = []

for i in lst1:
    if i in lst2:
        intersection.append(i)
    else:
        difference.append(i)

difference.extend(intersection)
lst1 = difference
print(lst1)
# ['pineapple', 'orange', 'pear', 'apple', 'banana']
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a simple (although not particularly efficient) way to solve the problem, using list comprehensions and respecting the original order:

```
lst1 = ["pineapple", "apple", "orange", "banana", "pear"]
lst2 = ["apple", "banana"]

head = [e for e in lst1 if e not in lst2]
tail = [e for e in lst1 if e in lst2]
lst1 = head + tail
```

If you want better performance (and still respect the original order), use a `set`:

```
intersect = set(lst1).intersection(lst2)
head = [e for e in lst1 if e not in intersect]
tail = [e for e in lst2 if e in intersect]
lst1 = head + tail
```

Either way, now `lst1` will be:

```
["pineapple", "orange", "pear", "apple", "banana"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Does the order of `'pineapple', 'orange' and 'pear'` matter? If not, then it can be done in a less verbose way:

```
lst1 = ["pineapple", "apple", "orange", "banana", "pear"]
lst2 =  ["apple", "banana"]

lst = list(set(lst1)-set(lst2))
lst.extend(lst2) ## ['orange', 'pear', 'pineapple', 'apple', 'banana']
```

**Edit:**

Since order does matter, this should work too:

```
lst = (set(lst1)-set(lst2))
lst = [i for i in lst1 if i in lst] ## added
lst.extend(lst2)
```